# Hibernate Last Updated Date

Tags: java, hibernate

How would I configure my hibernate hbm file to have a last updated date column? I'm trying to add a lastUpdated column to a legacy database structure. My DBA dislikes triggers and there are many places in the application which saves to the database.

Is there any lastUpdated property that I could add to my hbm or POJO which would automatically enter the time whenever hibernate insert/updates the object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to add `@PreUpdate` and `@PrePersist` (from JPA) and set up a [listener](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/listeners.html).

Comment: I unfortunately forgot to mention that my app uses java 4. Annotations are from java 5. Do you know of a java 4 friendly solution?

Comment: Sure, should be doable still by editing the hibernate.xml file using their [event system](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/events.html) and things like the [PreUpdateEventListener](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/event/PreUpdateEventListener.html).

Comment: According to what I've read, you can only use these 2 annotations if you are using an EntityManager.  I came across this article, which I think answers your question.  http://notatube.blogspot.com/2010/03/hibernate-using-event-listener-to-set.html  I haven't fixed mine yet, but this makes sense.